# how to get rid of the warning "ignoring broken ref refs/heads/animate2", where animate2 is a branch name

Tags: git

This warning is shown when I do

> git branch

I think at some point I deleted the animate2 branch, but may be it had uncommitted changes or something, I don't remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just delete the reference, though this might be slightly tricky: see example below.  Alternatively, you could clone your clone, or if there's nothing in it of value that is not already saved in some other clone, remove the entire clone.

Given that this particular reference is the *branch name* `animate2`,<sup>1</sup> you would potentially lose all commits that are *only* contained *in* that branch,<sup>2</sup> but if the ref is "broken" it's already not protecting commits.

Without having your specific broken ref to test, I can only create my own:

```
$ echo bad > .git/refs/heads/foo
$ git branch
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/foo
  dev
  diff-merge-base
* master
```

Any normal attempt to delete this fails:

```
$ git branch -d foo
error: branch 'foo' not found.
$ git branch -D foo
error: branch 'foo' not found.
```

Even the plumbing command `git update-ref` is stymied:

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/heads/foo
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/foo': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/foo': reference broken
```

so I can only resort to manual deletion:

```
$ rm .git/refs/heads/foo
```

This last method is not generally recommended, and probably won't work if the broken ref has been "packed" into `.git/packed-refs`; in that case you'd need to edit that file directly (and carefully).  But it does work for my own broken reference.

---

<sup>1</sup>Branches like `master`, tags like `v1.2`, remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, and many more forms that Git uses are all specific *kinds* of a general purpose mechanism that Git calls a *reference*.  All branch names have full names that start with `refs/heads/`.  All tag names have full names that start with `refs/tags/`.  All remote-tracking names really start with `refs/remotes/`, and go on to include the name of the remote, plus another slash.  This means that Git only needs one internal mechanism for all of these: it just reads through all refs, and if one of them is `refs/heads/dev`, that represents the *branch name* `dev`.

<sup>2</sup>A branch "contains commits" if those commits are *reachable from* the commit identified by the branch name.  All references just identify one particular commit or other object—branch names are constrained and must represent commits, while tag names can represent any object—but Git can start at *any* given commit and work backwards through the commit graph.  This means that a branch name need only indicate the *last* commit in the branch.  All commits reachable from that last commit are part of the branch.

This in turn implies that many commits are on *many branches at the same time*.  This reachability property is pretty central to Git.  See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

---

#### Sidebar: no *branch* has any uncommitted changes

> I think at some point I deleted the animate2 branch, but may be it had uncommitted changes or something ...

That's definitely *not* how the "broken ref" thing came about.  A "broken ref" is one for which the generic reference machinery in Git has set the `REF_BROKEN` flag:

```
/*
 * Reference cannot be resolved to an object name: dangling symbolic
 * reference (directly or indirectly), corrupt reference file,
 * reference exists but name is bad, or symbolic reference refers to
 * ill-formatted reference name.
 */
#define REF_ISBROKEN 0x04
```

(from [refs.h, near line 260](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017/refs.h#L257-L263)).

In fact, though, a *branch* in Git ... well, the word *branch* is ambiguous (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)), but the two things that *branch* should mean to you, in your head, are either:

1. A *name*, such as `master`, that internally will be a `refs/heads/` name or some other reference that you're going to use in "branch-like ways".  Remote-tracking names like `origin/master` are somewhat branch-like, and some people and documentation, including Git's, sometimes call them *remote branches*, or at least *remote-tracking branch names*.  (The *remote branches* term is one that I think is terribly sloppy and I try to avoid it at all times.)
2. The subset of the *commit graph* formed by taking the commit indicated by a branch-like name and working backwards.  (See both [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) and [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

Neither of these can hold uncommitted changes: one is just a name that holds a commit hash ID—a big ugly string like `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017`, and the other is a chain of commits.  So ... where *do* uncommitted changes exist?  The answer is that **they are in the index and/or in your work-tree**.

Your work-tree holds the set of files you can see and give to other programs to use.  You need a work-tree because the file snapshots that are inside each Git commit are stored in a special, read-only, compressed, Git-only form.  In the Git-only form, they can be re-used from one commit to another, but they literally cannot be changed.  If you can't *change* them, you can't get any new work done.  So you need a place where they're de-Git-ified, turned back into ordinary read/write files, and that's your work-tree.

The *index* is a special Git data structure—which is actually mostly stored in an ordinary file, `.git/index`—that Git uses, that sits *between* your current commit—the one you have checked out as `HEAD`—and your work-tree.  This thing, this index, is very central to the process of making *new* commits.  It holds a copy<sup>3</sup> of *every file* taken out of the commit you are working on now, just like the work-tree holds a copy of every file.  The copy in the index is in the special frozen Git *format*, but—unlike the ones in commits—isn't actually *frozen*.  You can replace it with a new copy any time, by using `git add` to take your work-tree version and prepare it for Git and overwrite the index version.

The index is so important (and/or the name "index" is so bad) that it has two more names.  It's also called the *staging area*, to reflect its job of holding your *proposed next commit*, and (rarely these days) the *cache*, to reflect its job of sitting between the current commit and the work-tree.

When `git status` says that some change is *staged for commit*, what this really means is that the copy of that file that's in the index is different from the copy of the file that's in the `HEAD` commit.  When `git status` says that some change is *not staged for commit*, what this really means is that the copy of the file that's in the index is different from the copy of the file that's in the work-tree.

So *uncommitted changes* are those in the index and/or the work-tree.  They're not actually *in* any branch at all.  You can be *on* some branch—as in, `git status` will say `on branch xyz`—and have those uncommitted changes in the index and your work-tree, but they're not *in* `xyz` at all.  If you make a new commit—which snapshots whatever is in the *index*, which is why you have to `git add` all the time to copy from your work-tree to the index—then the new commit becomes the tip commit of the branch.  *Now* they're "in `xyz`", but they're not *uncommitted* any more.

"Deleting a branch" consists of deleting the *branch name*.  That's all that you have to do: just *delete the name*, and with it, the stored hash ID of the last commit: the commit that you say is the end of the branch.  The commit itself is still there.  If it's unprotected—unreachable: see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) again—Git will eventually throw out the commits too.